# Convert Map to Custom Map

Tags: java, lambda

```
Map<String, String> characterMap = new HashMap<>();
characterMap.put("Manikanta", "Pretty");
characterMap.put("Amulya", "VeryGood");
characterMap.put("Saroja", "Good");
characterMap.put("Vinitha", "Cool");
characterMap.put("Sravani", "Good");
characterMap.put("Sameera", "Good");

/*String key = characterMap.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Good")).map(Map.Entry::getKey).findFirst().orElse(null);*/

Map<String, String> comboMap = new HashMap<>();
String newKey = null;
String val1 = null;
String val2 = null;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : characterMap.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Manikanta"))
        newKey = entry.getKey();

    if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Amulya"))
        val1 = entry.getValue();

    if (entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Vinitha"))
        val2 = entry.getValue();
}

comboMap.put(newKey, val1 + "_" + val2);
```

How can I implement this in a lambda expression? Is it really possible to insert existing map data to customize to add new map like the above code?

Comment: Are you adding only one entry to the new map?

Comment: Yes, I am adding one entry with multiple values combination as value in new map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only check on the key values, you don't even need a for loop:

```
comboMap.put(characterMap.containsKey("Manikanta")?"Manikanta":null,
             characterMap.get("Amulya")+ "_" + characterMap.get("Vinitha"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You're attempting to reduce a map with 6 elements into, evidently, a map with a single element in it (if this is an example, and the resulting map will ever contain anything but exactly 1 key of value "Manikanta" -> "VeryGood_Cool", you're going to need to update your example).

streams (I gather that is what you mean by 'in lambda expression') excel at operating on a single element in the stream (so, say, the notion "Saroja"->"Good"), *or* on how to turn the entire stream into a different collection (such as: Turn the whole thing into a list of keys).

You could write a custom collector; it would not be any shorter than this code is, and would be a lot harder to read. Hence I don't see the point of showing that.